# Converting from char* to int

Tags: c

My code fails and returns a really big number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "hello123";
    printf("%d\n",*(int *)s);
    return 0;
}
```

with atoi it returns 0, any ideas?

What im trying to achieve is:
for example im sending "hello123" to a server software, the server software should get the "123" numeric in the string, doing this by this method:

```
uint16_t get_uint16(NetworkMessage *message)
{
    uint16_t ret = 0;
    if (!message || !message->buffer)
        return 0;

    ret = *(uint16_t *)(message->buffer + message->position);
    message->position += sizeof(uint16_t);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: why using `*(int *)s`? Explain it.

Comment: @Mark: trying to get the "123" by position in my network message (in another program)

Comment: What would the expected result be the string was "h8llo123"?

Comment: Ive added more information, please check it out (more explained)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes your string has two parts, the first indeces holding chars (eg `hello`) and the last indeces holding the number (eg `123`). From what I understand from your comments this is what you wanted to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
     char* s = "hello123";
     char* num_ptr = s;

     while(*num_ptr < '0' || *num_ptr > '9')
          ++num_ptr;

     int number = atoi(num_ptr);

     printf("%d\n", number);
     return 0; 
}
```

---

After edit : Try that? I assume `message_buffer` contains your message and is of type `char*`

```
int get_number(char* message_buffer)
{
     char* num_ptr = message_buffer + strlen(message_buffer) - 1;

     while(isdigit(num_ptr) && num_ptr > message_buffer)
          --num_ptr;

     int number = atoi(num_ptr);

     if(number > UINT16_RANGE)
          //Handle error here

     return number;     
}


uint16_t get_uint16(NetworkMessage *message) 
{
     uint16_t ret = 0;
     if (!message || !message->buffer)
         return 0;      

     ret = get_number(message->buffer);
     //message->position += sizeof(uint16_t);     
     return ret; 
}
```

Comment: @Fallen, what is the exact contents of `message->buffer` ?

Comment: @Muggen: fixed, thank you, ive voted you up and accepted your answer!

Comment: @Fallen, oops I had a mistake on the code. add a `-1` on the `strlen()` line plz.

Comment: @Fallen, `itoa()` returns an `int`, but you use `uint16_t` which might be smaller if your int is `32bit` make sure you take care of all error conditions in the `//Handle error here` I added.

Comment: Even after fixes (isdigit(*num_ptr) and off-by-one error in a while loop), get_number("hello123a4") would return 4, while my atoi_skip("hello123a4") would return 123.

Comment: @Goran, I have the impression it should return 4. Also, the way you wrote atoi_skip will fail in your example, because it will end up with `123a4` and not just `123`. The assumption made is, that only the last digits in the string will represent the number wanted. Also, there is indeed a `*num_ptr` error, but where do you see the off by one in the while loop ?

Comment: It will not fail, atoi converts the initial portion and ignore ending non digits, atoi("123a4") is 123. Should the solution return 4 or 123 is up to the OP.

Comment: @Goran, you are right about atoi. Also, the OP somehow gave that direction from an answer in his question. `"h8llo123"` should return `123`, not `8`. Look on the comments in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.  You can't convert text to a number and expect it to figure out what numbers you want.

A string is an array of characters, which each have an ASCII value.  By casting to `(int*)`, it takes the ASCII value of the first 4 characters (4 bytes to an int) and creates one huge number out of it.

In your example, the ASCII values of the first 4 characters are `{ 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c }`.  Now you reverse the order for little endian systems to `{ 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x68 }`.  You combine these into `0x6c6c6568`.  Converting that to decimal is `1,819,043,176`.  Which is the number you get in your output.

If you just want the 123 you have to use clever string parsing to parse out the `hello`, and then use `atoi()` on the remaining.

Comment: Ive added more info to main post, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `atoi(s)`.

In your code, you are casting string pointer to integer pointer, reading first four bytes of a string as some large integer. `int atoi(char*)` will do a proper parsing, returning integer value.

Parsing "hello123" it will stop on first non numeric character, and return 0. You may skip non numeric characters, testing with `int isdigit(char)`:

```
int atoi_skip(char *s) {
        while(*s != '\0' && !isdigit(*s)) s++; /* skip non digits */
        return atoi(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else is absolutely right.  You can't convert a character array to an integer by using a cast.  It doesn't work that way.  In C, chars are represented by integers.  When you write:

```
char *s = "hello123";
```

What you're getting is an array with a bunch of characters in it.  You could equivalently write:

```
char *s = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

Thus, when you're calling `printf("%d\n",*(int *)s);`, what you're doing is casting the memory address of your character array to a pointer to an integer.  You're then taking the contents of this integer and printing that.  I'm pretty sure the result you'll get will depend on the system you're using, but it's definitely not what you want.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
printf("%d\n", atoi(&(s[5]));
```