# Convert chars from pointer to integer num

Tags: c

if the user enter a string,than is save every part of it with strtok, and one of the part was numbers, how i can convert this numbers to integer?
my goal is to get this string : "matrix 3 3 ", and to verify that the user didnt enter double or float, just integer num. I tried to do casting but it is didnt work
thx!

Comment: Please show your attempts, otherwise it's hard to tell what you've done wrong.

Comment: The library function you need is called `strtol`.

Comment: Maybe this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556509/converting-from-char-to-int

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible ways, but concerning

> my goal is [...] to verify that the user didnt enter double or float, just integer num.

you probably aim for full input validation. In that case, you must use [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "42"; // in your code, some result from strtok

    char *endptr;
    long num = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

    if (endptr == str || *endptr)
    {
        // not parsed successfully
        return 1; // error and out ... do whatever is suitable
    }
    if (num > INT_MAX || num < INT_MIN)
    {
        // value was outside int range
        return 1;
    }

    int x = (int)num;
    return 0;
}
```

If you actually want a `long`, for checking the range, set `errno` to `0` before calling `strtol()` and check for `errno == ERANGE` afterwards. (include `errno.h` for this)

---

For the sake of completeness, in response [to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174789/convert-chars-from-pointer-to-integer-num/50174894?noredirect=1#comment87367828_50174894), of course you can do it all manually, but it's tedious and error prone and less efficient, so I'd never recommend that. See here an example for parsing **unsigned** integers from strings, with error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// write result to *result, return 0 on error, 1 on success:
int parseuint(unsigned int *result, const char *str)
{
    if (!str || !*str) return 0;

    size_t len = strlen(str);
    unsigned char bcd[len];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') return 0;
        bcd[i] = str[i] - '0';
    }

    size_t scanstart = 0;
    *result = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    while (scanstart < len)
    {
        if (!mask) return 0;
        if (bcd[len-1] & 1) *result |= mask;
        mask <<=1;
        for (size_t i = len-1; i > scanstart; --i)
        {
            bcd[i] >>= 1;
            if (bcd[i-1] & 1) bcd[i] |= 8;
        }
        bcd[scanstart] >>= 1;
        while (scanstart < len && !bcd[scanstart]) ++scanstart;
        for (size_t i = scanstart; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (bcd[i] > 7) bcd[i] -= 3;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a;

    if (parseuint(&a, "4258"))
    {
        printf("parsed: %u\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("error parsing 4258");
    }

    if (parseuint(&a, "13.7"))
    {
        printf("parsed: %u\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("error parsing 13.7");
    }

    if (parseuint(&a, "12345678901234567890"))
    {
        printf("parsed: %u\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("error parsing 12345678901234567890");
    }
}
```

Comment: THX , but i have to use only in <stdio.h> and <string.h>. sorry that i didnt mention that....

Comment: That's impossible except coding it all manually (which is error prone and inefficient). You can't even use `atoi()` then (which wouldn't do the validity check as requested, like suggested in the other now deleted answer). The only way I could think of is manually checking every single character for `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` and then use `sscanf()` on it. But this would still not check whether the number is in the correct range.

Comment: OK, so i think in another direction. I need to get from the user this string; "matrix i j " , matrix is the name of the matrix, and i and j is the raws and col. first I tried to get this string with strtok, and than i got 3 strings of martix, i , and j. Do you have any idea how i can get from the users the 'matrix' as a string and the numbers of raws and col(i and j) as integrs? thank you

Comment: User input is **always** characters. That's why you need functions like `atoi()` and `strtol()` and they are defined in `stdlib.h` -- because it's defined that way in the C standard.

Comment: @matanlalush I added a simple example of **manual** number parsing. But take it more as an example to demonstrate why you **don't** want to do that ....